# How to encode binary to a DNA sequence

Tags: php, string, encoding, binary, bioinformatics

I would like to encode a binary sequence to a DNA sequence by following this rule:

```
00 = A
01 = C
10 = G
11 = T
```

For example: `10011100` = `GCTA`.

I wrote a PHP script which converts my string to binary and then I convert the binary to a DNA sequence by using the `str_replace` function. My issue is that the DNA sequence is not correctly converted. Can someone help me?

Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php
// Function to convert string to bin
function strToBin($input) {
    if (!is_string($input))
        return false;
    $ret = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        $temp = decbin(ord($input{$i}));
        $ret .= str_repeat('0', 8 - strlen($temp)) . $temp;
    }
    return $ret;
}
$bin = strToBin('Stack');
// Try to transcript binary to DNA
$bincomb = array('00', '01', '10', '11');
$DNAtrans = array('A', 'C', 'G', 'T');

echo $transcript = str_replace($bincomb, $DNAtrans, $bin);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str_replace()` approach doesn't work because it looks for the substrings in the order `00`, `01`, `10`, `11`. So, for example, with the binary string `1001` it replaces the inner `00` with an `A`, after which the string is `1A1`, and no more conversions can be made.

For your function to work, you need to go through the binary string in chunks of two characters.

```
$bin = strToBin('Stack');

$bin = str_split($bin, 2);

$combine = array(
    '00' => 'A',
    '01' => 'C',
    '10' => 'G',
    '11' => 'T'
);

$str = '';

foreach ($bin as $item)
    $str .= $combine[$item];
```

The string is first split into chunks of two characters, which are then looped through and their respective values appended to the result string `$str`.

Comment: Hi @Antti29, many thanks for your help and your explanations. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, I usually do these transformations with the two-arguments implementation of `strtr()`, like this:

```php
// outputs 10011100

echo strtr("GCTA", array("A" => "00", "C" => "01", "G" => "10", "T" => "11"));
```

The reverse is also possible:

```
// outputs GCTA
```

echo strtr("10011100", array("00" =>"A", "01" => "C", "10" => "G", "11" => "T"));